# Is there control(view) for android that I can use to take user signature?

Tags: android

I would like to allow user to sign on a screen with stylus like UPS or Credit Card terminal in store.

Is there control/api I can use in my program to convert this to image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such control. But you can implement yours easily. Take a look at [this example](http://eleanordarephdjournal.blogspot.com/2011/03/simple-android-touch-screen-move-image.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html), track finger movements and generate a bitmap. You will probably want to create a custom View to handle this things.

You should read up on [Creating custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) and come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for exactly the same thing.
I tried to base my work on [FingerPaint Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html)

I created a layout with a View, but I don't know how I can join the view in my layout to the class used in finger paint example.